# Is there an alternate way to restore the boot loader if I want to uninstall Ubuntu? The normal way doesn't seem to work

Tags: grub2, uninstall

So I want to get rid of Ubuntu (I am dual booting with Windows as my original OS) because I don't really need it anymore and it is taking up some much-needed space. I've tried following this tutorial on Youtube but the method for restoring the bootloader, which is the same method I have seen online everywhere, is not working. After I boot back up, the grub menu is still there. This is the video I am using: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWe9zlSmzjA If anyone wants to watch it feel free if not I will post the steps from the video that I followed at the end of my question.

One thing I was considering was factory resetting my laptop because I need to do it anyways because it is going through some issues. I have seen on some posts that you keep the Ubuntu partition but the boot loader is restored to normal so you can't actually access Ubuntu. Would I just be able to delete the Ubuntu partition through Windows after I am done factory resetting my laptop and call it a day?

Steps I followed: 
From Windows, hold shift and press restart -> prompted to a screen that says "Please Wait"

Screen that says "Choose an Option" pops up with "Continue" "Troubleshoot" "Tun Off Your PC" as options.

Click on Troubleshoot -> Advanced Options -> Command Prompt

After that system restarts, greeted by what account I want to log in; log in with my account.

Taken to the command prompt where I type bootrec /fixmbr followed by bootrec /fixboot the close command prompt and click on "Continue" on the screen that pops up. EDIT: I just tried to restore the loader again and now I am getting "Access is denied" when running the bootrec /fixboot command

Boot loader should no longer be accessible. (Yet for me it still is)

Back in windows, go to disk management and select Ubuntu partition and delete volume then delete partition and go to the windows partition and extend the volume to merge memory back together

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain the method. Don't expect people to sit through random video tutorials in order to help you. We also need to see he commands you ran *exactly* since one possible source of error is that you didn't follow the tutorial correctly.

Comment: Not that I recommend you wanting people to watch the video to help you, but the video is showing the right commands and just like @terdon said, you could have ran the commands incorrectly.

Comment: @anurupr yeah I edited the steps I followed into my post for those that don't want to watch. But I have tried following these steps many times and they are the same commands I see everywhere else. I highly doubt I could have typed them in incorrectly like 5+ times in a row

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-10-bootrec-fixboot-access-is-denied/747c4180-7ff3-4bc2-b6cc-81e572d546df?auth=1 . Have you seen this?